# Getting error while fetching emails via imap

Tags: php, imap

i have problem in IMAP 
i am writing below code to fetch inbox emails

```
$hostname = '{mail.test.in:110}INBOX';
$username='name';
$password='password';
$inbox = imap_open($hostname, $username, $password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());
```

i am getting error

```
"message": "imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {mail.innovify.in:110}INBOX"
```

please let me know solution

Comment: Reading the [mailbox section of the imap_open() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php) it looks like you need to provide a service. Does `$hostname = '{mail.innovify.in:110/pop3}INBOX';` make any difference?

Comment: port 110 is usually for POP3 mailboxes so you might need to add something like `'{mail.innovify.in:110/pop3}INBOX'` have a look at the [manual entry](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php). Standard imap uses port 143 or 993 via ssl

Comment: Thanks Dezza i got solution by placing pop3 :)

Comment: Good to hear that you got it sorted - I've added this as an answer for future reference. If I helped you could accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [`imap_open()` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php) you need to provide a service flag if you are not using IMAP.

You are using port 110 which is for POP3, so you need to let `imap_open()` know about that by changing your connection string from

`$hostname = '{mail.test.in:110}INBOX';`

to

`$hostname = '{mail.test.in:110/pop3}INBOX';`